# Deadlock in script for sending emails

Tags: php, mysql, database, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have a script for sending emails in the background. The script runs in parallel to send out multiple emails simultaneously. It works basically like this, with a mixture of MySQL and PHP:

```sql
/* TransmissionId is a PRIMARY KEY */
/* StatusId is a FOREIGN KEY */
/* Token is UNIQUE */

/* Pick a queued (StatusId=1) transmission and set it to pending (StatusId=2) */
/* This is a trick to both update a row and store its id for later retrieval in one query */
SET @Ids = 0;
UPDATE transmission
SET StatusId=IF(@Ids := TransmissionId,2,2), LatestStatusChangeDate=NOW()
WHERE StatusId = 1
ORDER BY TransmissionId ASC
LIMIT 1;

/* Fetch the id of the picked transmission */
$Id = SELECT @Ids;

try {
    /* Fetch the email and try to send it */
    $Email = FetchEmail($Id);
    $Email->Send();

    /* Set the status to sent (StatusId=3) */
    $StatusId = 3;
} catch(Exception $E) {
    /* The email could not be sent, set the status to failed (StatusId=4) */
    $StatusId = 4;
} finally {
    /* Save the new transmission status */
    UPDATE transmission
    SET StatusId=$StatusId, LatestStatusChangeDate=NOW(), Token='foobar'
    WHERE TransmissionId = $Id;
}
```

The issue is that I sometimes get a deadlock: `SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`. This has happened when executing the last query. I've not seen it happen when executing the first query. Can anyone understand how a deadlock can happen in this case? Could it be that the first query and the last query lock `StatusId` and `TransmissionId` in opposite order? But I don't think the first query needs to lock `TransmissionId`, nor do I think the last query needs to lock `StatusId`. How can I find this out, and how can I fix it?

## Edit

There is another query that might also play a role. Whenever someone opens the email, this query is run:

```sql
/* Selector is UNIQUE */
UPDATE transmission SET
OpenCount=OpenCount+1
WHERE Selector = 'barfoo'
```

Comment: How long does it take to send all emails? Have you considered using a transaction and locking underlying rows for update?

Comment: Well, if you have scripts running in parallel it can happened a lot. Our solution was to avoid updating multiple line at the same time. It avoid that kind of error.

Some mySQL table type are using transaction even if you don't specify them.

Deadlocks are here just to not having 2 processes trying to modify the same data at the same time. It happens a lot when you parallelize some processes.

Comment: @mike Every email takes a few seconds to send. I have considered this, but don't understand why it should be necessary.

Comment: @RaphaëlGonçalves None of my queries update multiple rows at the same time. The first query could potentially do it, but only one row is updated because of `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: InnoDB uses automatic row-level locking. You can get deadlocks even in the case of transactions that just insert or delete a single row. That is because these operations are not really “atomic”; they automatically set locks on the (possibly several) index records of the row inserted or deleted. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html

Comment: @RaphaëlGonçalves Thanks, if you add your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB uses automatic row-level locking. You can get deadlocks even in the case of transactions that just insert or delete a single row. That is because these operations are not really “atomic”; they automatically set locks on the (possibly several) index records of the row inserted or deleted. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.ht‌​ml